# how to serialize a dictionary <MyClass, string>

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

I have a class I built, so I have control over that. My problem is the following:

I am trying to send an http request (put) with some content on the body.

```
var dictJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);

var test = await _httpClient.PutAsync($"myurl", new StringContent(dictJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

the problem is that I am trying to send a `Dictionary<MyClass, string>`, so I pass the dictionary fine, but the problem is at the serialization. Then after serializing I have the right values but instead of the objects, I have the name of the class, so "MyClass" instead.

I have tried serializing directly the dictionary with no success, I also tried the following:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
    var t = kvp.Key.ToString();
    dictionary.Add(kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp.Value);
}
```

Still getting the same result, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the before and after its serialized? It seems that attempting to set a class instance as a key in a dictionary is complicated. It likely needs a hash value. Its very possible that you should change the `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was very simple and it worked for me.

The main problem with my code was that when serializing I did not get the object but a string describing the object... so if it has to be a string, and not an object the solution was very simple: convert the object to a string first, then serialize the dictionary.

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach(var kvp in dict)
        {
            var t = kvp.Key.ToString();
            var m = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kvp.Key);
            dictionary.Add(m, kvp.Value);
        }
        var dictJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
```

Comment: Could this be inside a TypeConverter? You don't happen to have an example of using this in one do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `MyObject` as a key in JSON.
From [Newtonsoft serialization guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm)

> When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding ToString() for the key type or by implementing a TypeConverter. A TypeConverter will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.

Instead of you can transit your dictionary in JSON structure like this:`[{ Key: 'your key from a dictionary', Value = 'your value from a dictionary'}]`

Simple implementation:

```
    class SimpleKeyValue<TK, TValue>
    {
        public TK Key { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
    }

    Dictionary<MyClass, int> dict = new Dictionary<MyClass, int>{
        {new MyClass() {Id = 1}, 1},
        {new MyClass() {Id = 2}, 2},
        {new MyClass() {Id = 3}, 3},
        {new MyClass() {Id = 4}, 4}
    };

    var simpleKeyValues = dict.Select(item => new SimpleKeyValue<MyClass, int>
    {
        Key = item.Key,
        Value = item.Value
    });

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(simpleKeyValues);

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SimpleKeyValue<MyClass, int>>>(json)
        .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```